# Why is my state iterations being overwritten?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

Hi so I'm not sure as to why the items in my hook are being overwritten and only the last value stays saved in it.

Up to the point where I am looping through the xml everything works fine. The `setCampgrounds()` hook is not saving all the iterations. I would have thought that the `...campgrounds` spread would make a copy of the previous iteration so it wouldn't get overwritten. Is there something I'm not understanding inside the loop or what would be the correct way to save these items inside my campgrounds hook?

```
const [campgrounds, setCampgrounds] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
        url = some url...
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => res.data)
            .then((str) => {
                let newXML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
                let results = newXML.getElementsByTagName("result");
                for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    setCampgrounds([...campgrounds, {
                        facilityID: results[i].getAttribute("facilityID"), 
                        facilityName: results[i].getAttribute("facilityName"),
                        contractID: results[i].getAttribute("contractID")
                    }]);   
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
            
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`campgrounds` is the same current state value for each state update you are enqueueing, so each update is overwritten by the next and the last one to set state is the update the persists.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to enqueue each update. Each enqueued update uses the result state from the previous update.

[Functional Updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```
const [campgrounds, setCampgrounds] = useState([]);

...

for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  setCampgrounds(campgrounds => [
    ...campgrounds,
    {
      facilityID: results[i].getAttribute("facilityID"),
      facilityName: results[i].getAttribute("facilityName"),
      contractID: results[i].getAttribute("contractID")
    }
  ]);
}
```